# Choose what zoomlevel to read from for mbtiles file in GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, mbtiles

GDAL is supposed to [read MBTiles files](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html) and to do so, it selects the highest zoomlevel available. However, is there a way to choose another zoomlevel? i.e. override the default and go for a lower one?

I'm currently accessing the file like this (and it defaults to the highest zoomlevel):

```
gdal_translate tiles.mbtiles export.tiff
```

Comment: The lower zoom levels are probably registered as overviews.  How are you accessing the data?  Normal overview access should work (in RasterIO) or maybe GDALRasterBand::GetOverview() (although I've never used that fx).

Comment: I'm accessing the data with gdal_translate only, how can I access the overviews from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gdal_translate's [Dataset open option `-oo`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) allows to specify [MBTiles opening options](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html).

To answer the question, you can get e.g. zoom level 12 by doing:
`gdal_translate -oo ZOOM_LEVEL=12 tiles.mbtiles export.tiff`

Comment: can we make various zoom level such as min zoom 8 and max zoom 22?

Comment: @Husni I think if you want to have multiple zoom levels you have to run `gdal_translate` multiple times and pass a different zoom level each time.