# Python, GDAL2 translate and MbTiles options

Tags: python, gdal, zoom, gdal-translate, mbtiles

I try to apply this answer :

[Choose what zoomlevel to read from for mbtiles file in GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83902/choose-what-zoomlevel-to-read-from-for-mbtiles-file-in-gdal)

to a gdal call from python (witout using os.system() / subprocess.call() ) but i can't find how i should add the **"-oo ZOOM_LEVEL=12"** GDAL Parameter to my code :

```
ds = gdal.Open('c:\data.mbtiles')
ds = gdal.Translate('c:\data.png', ds, format="PNG")
```

any advices ?